# "Dash" is not accessedPylance / Import "Dash" could not be resolvedPylance

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am using VS Code in Windows 10 laptop. I created a virtual environment named "dashboards" using the command "python -m venv dashboards" now installed the dash using "pip install dash" and finally activated the virtual environment using "dashboards\Scripts\activate" .

Now I created a file sample.py in which I have written "import Dash" but don't know why getting this error "Import "Dash" could not be resolvedPylance". VS Code shows that I am using "Python 3.7.4 64-bit (dashboards':venv)" at the bottom left. I tried to change the interpreter using Cntrl+ Shft + P but it shows only one interpretor "Python 3.7.4 64-bit ('base':conda).

Please help me what should I do to make things work. I guess I made some mistake in settings of vs code but not sure what.

[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r4XKP.png)

Answer (score 2):

The interpreter environments were detected by the Python Extension automatically in the [following locations](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_where-the-extension-looks-for-environments).

After you created a virtual environment, you need to reload the VSCode to make it be detected and added to the environment list.

**Update:**

**First,** you need to make sure you have created the `dashboards` environment and installed the packages successfully. It will be looks like this:

[image]

[image]

**Second,** you need to make sure you are using the `dashboards` environments. You can execute this code to check it:

```
import sys
print(sys.executable)
```

If it still not work, you can try to delete the cache of the VSCode:

The `workspaceStorage` and `globalStorage` folder under this location:

```
C:\Users\{UserName}\AppData\Roaming\Code\User
```

Comment: Yes I did that but when I am pressing Cntrl + Shift + P , it is not showing the virtual environment

Comment: Thanks for your response, could you have a look at the update of this answer? If it still not working, please feel free to let me know.